# Reliability/validity required for the mean of combined items?

Tags: mean, survey, validity, cronbachs-alpha

Let's just say that the 4 items making one construct are not well correlating (for whatever reason) and their Cronbach is 0.62 despite loading into 1 factor. Is there an alternative way to proceed? Can I skip Cronbach/validity issues/factor analysis by just summing all 4 items and then getting their mean by dividing the total sum by 4? After that, I can use the new mean (variable) as a dependent one in my regression analysis. Has this been done before? Is it an acceptable practice?

Comment: By "loading into 1 factor" do you mean that you performed a factor analysis, that factor analysis had a one factor solution, and all items loaded on that one factor? Or simply that you believe the four items should all be indicators of the same latent construct?

Comment: They all actually loaded on 1 factor but their Cronbach reliability is low (0.62). Therefore, if I proceed with this, it will be a mess of reliability/validity. I am asking if I can skip all of this and go directly to the alternative suggested above.

Comment: How many observations did you have for the factor analysis, and were the variables ordinal or some continuous type?

Comment: Around 180. All are Likert-scale items (back to the debate of ordinal vs continuous). However, the low reliability is bothering me. I tested a regression model with both the factor scores and the summed mean; both results were approximately similar (and significant). I just want to skip reliability/validity of this problematic construct since its Cronbach is low.

Comment: You may want to read around formative measurement models where less emphasis is placed on reliability. However, if you're certain that your items come from a formative measurement model then you may just have to accept that your final scores are likely to be unreliable.

Comment: They should be representing one construct since I adopted it from somewhere with a high alpha (0.85). The mistake I made was probably to change some wording which had a bad effect. Also, if my composite reliability is above 0.7, is this safe to proceed? Can you have such high difference between Cronbach (0.62) and CR (0.74)?

Comment: That sounds like quite important details that ought to be edited into the question. You may also want to rewrite the question to make clear exactly what you want to know, as there seems to be a lot of questions you're seeking answers for.

Comment: I prefer to keep this question as it is. I will post separately about 'Cronbach VS CR'. Thank you.